# Using SQL to exclude a word that comes after a phrase

Tags: sql, postgresql

This issue might be a bit too complicated for SQL to handle, but since I have pretty intermediate SQL skills perhaps someone more well-versed in SQL than me will know how to fix the below issue.

I am looking to isolate observations that mention a keyword that occur after a phrase. An example would be like below: For variable FREE_TEXT I want to isolate where the word orange is said AFTER the phrase Excluding This:

FREE_TEXT=
"Including This:

The best fruit is an apple

Excluding This:

The worst fruit is an orange"

Technically I could just do where FREE_TEXT not like '%orange%' but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking to specifically isolate for when a word is said AFTER the phrase Excluding This.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: What is the expected output? You want the whole `FREE_TEXT` to be returned when there is an `ORANGE` after `Excluding this`?

Answer (score 0):

This will find the word `orange` in the string after the phrase `Excluding This`

```
select  STRPOS(SUBSTRING(free_text 
                         , position('Excluding This' in free_text) 
                           + length('Excluding This'))
                         , 'orange') 
from test
```

I have used `position` function to find the position of the string `Excluding This` because I wanted to start my search after that string. The `position` function returned the position of the character `E` of the string `Excluding This`so I had to add length of that expresion to find the wanted position from where I start my search.

After I had my position from where I will start my search, and I had the keyword that I need to find it was easy to use string functions `STRPOS` and `SUBSTRING` to check if the string value in the column `free_text` contains word `orange`.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e71524c857bc5a6da755a1f7930cb08)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your sample data correct, this following logic should help you getting your expected output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5bfc73dfd92ca43670dd207e9c127091)

```
WITH your_table (FREE_TEXT)
AS
(
    SELECT 'T Including This: The best fruit is an apple' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Including This: The best fruit is an orange' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Excluding This: The best fruit is an apple' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T Excluding This: The worst fruit is an orange'
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE strpos(FREE_TEXT, 'Excluding This:') = 0
OR strpos(FREE_TEXT, 'Excluding This:') > strpos(FREE_TEXT, 'orange')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where free_text like '%Excluding this%orange%'
```